# CodeIgniter - Ajax file upload - not uploading the file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm having a form inside a bootstrap modal window, in which I upload some files.

This is my script

```
<?php

/**
 * Handle the file uploading for the article
 */
public function upload_ajax() {
    $this->output->enable_profiler(false);

    // check if the article has been created
    if (!$this->input->post('post_id')) {
        // do something here ..
    } else {
        // set upload configs
        $dir = FCPATH . '/posts';
        $config = array(
            'upload_path' => $dir,
            'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
            'max_width' => '1024',
            'max_height' => '768',
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        // try to upload the file
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
            $response = array(
                'status' => '400',
                'message' => $this->upload->display_errors(),
            );
        } else {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $response = array(
                'status' => '200',
                'message' => '<p>The image uploaded successfully</p>',
            );
        }
    }

    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
        ->set_output(json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES))->_display();
    exit();
}
```

the javascript

```
$('#btn-upload').on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url : url, // the value from the form action attribute
    type : 'post',
    data : {
      'post_id' : $('[name="postID"]').val(),
      'userfile' : $('[name="userfile"]').val(),
      'name' : $('[name="userfile"]').attr('name'),
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(response) {
      $('#upload-results').removeClass('alert alert-success alert-danger').html('');

      if (response.status == 200) {
        $('.upload-form').hide();
        $('#upload-results').addClass('alert alert-success').html(response.message);
      }

      if (response.status == 400) {
        $('.upload-form').show();
        $('#upload-results').addClass('alert alert-danger').html(response.message);
      }
    },
  });
});
```

and the view

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="upload-results"></div>

    <?php echo form_open_multipart('posts/upload_ajax', array('class' => 'form-horizontal upload-form')); ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="postID"/>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Image Upload</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div data-provides="fileinput" class="fileinput fileinput-new">
                <input type="hidden">

                <div data-trigger="fileinput" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;" class="fileinput-new thumbnail">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('img/default.jpg'); ?>">
                </div>
                <div style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 6px;" class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail"></div>
                <div> 
                    <span class="btn btn-white btn-file"> 
                        <span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span> 
                        <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span> 
                        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="userfile"/> 
                    </span>
                    <a data-dismiss="fileinput" class="btn btn-orange fileinput-exists" href="#">Remove</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div><!-- /.modal-body -->
```

The problem is that even if I have selected an image, I always get the validation error `"You did not select a file to upload"` that comes form the Upload library. However on firebug I can see the 3 variables I'm sending with the ajax request

```
'post_id' : $('[name="postID"]').val(), // shows e.g. 12
'userfile' : $('[name="userfile"]').val(), // shows e.g. my-image.jpg
'name' : $('[name="userfile"]').attr('name'), // shows userfile
```

I have also tried this

```
$userfile = $this->input->post('name');
if (!$this->upload->do_upload($userfile))
```

but no luck. How can I make this work properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sending file we use  `formData` in ajax

```
var formData = new FormData(this);
$.ajax({
                url : url, // the value from the form action attribute
                type : 'post', 
                data : formData
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
        dataType : 'json',
                success : function(response) {
                    $('#upload-results').removeClass('alert alert-success alert-danger').html('');

                    if (response.status == 200) {
                        $('.upload-form').hide();
                        $('#upload-results').addClass('alert alert-success').html(response.message);
                    }

                    if (response.status == 400) {
                        $('.upload-form').show();
                        $('#upload-results').addClass('alert alert-danger').html(response.message);
                    }
                },
            });
```

In php side check value with

```
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
```

Comment: Do I also need and these too ? `cache: false`,
                `contentType: false`,
                `processData: false`, or are opional ?

Comment: I get this error on firebug: `TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.` that points to var formData = new FormData(this);

Comment: okk try with `var form = $('form')[0]; 
var formData = new FormData(form);`

Comment: Could you also give me some additional help in one more thing? I'm planning to use bootstrap progress bar to display the progress  of the uploading, but Im not sure how to do this

Comment: I am a not much aware of bootstarp!!

Comment: I mean about the javascript - jquery ajax functionality